# upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload cloudinary

Tags: httprequest, angular8, cloudinary

am trying to upload files directly from my front-end(Angular 8) using the cloudinary API_URL but am still getting the same bad request (400) and the same error "Upload preset must be whitelisted for unsigned uploads" even i tried different solutions like providing the preset_name in the FormData and setting the preset to unsigned in my cloudinary settings but still not working. is there any solution ?

my upload code :

```
 const images = new FormData();
images.append('images', file);
images.append('upload_preset', [presetName]);
this.progressBar = true

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/[cloudName]/image/upload', images, 
    {
     reportProgress: true,
  
   });
this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
  } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Upload preset must be whitelisted for unsigned uploads` error means that that the preset you are using is marked for Signed uploads. Since you are not performing an authenticated API call, i.e. using a signature, the upload preset must be set as Unsigned. If you haven't already, go to the Settings -> Upload tab in your account and verify that the Signing Mode is set to Unsigned for the preset you are trying to use.

In addition, I see that you are passing a parameter called 'images'. This is not a valid parameter for the [Upload](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) API. Please update that to "file".

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);
data.append("upload_preset", "default-preset");
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! it worked perfectly ! i appreciate your help

Comment: Another case that can lead to this error is if the preset is indeed unsigned however the value of the preset is not sent to Cloudinary or if its value is blank in the request. Details in another post I shared - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75953493/11707957