# ้how to upload image to cloudinary with (MERN)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cloudinary

this error when submit form
POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dvq5qpz3n/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)
{"error":{"message":"Upload preset must be whitelisted for unsigned uploads"}}

form.jsx

```
const uploadImageToCloudinary = async (imageFile) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageFile);
    formData.append("upload_preset", process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET);
  
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dvq5qpz3n/image/upload`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }
    );
  
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.secure_url;
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    if (image) {
      try {
        const uploadedImageUrl = await uploadImageToCloudinary(image);
        const newBlog = {
          title,
          description,
          image: uploadedImageUrl,
        };
  
        await createBlog (newBlog).unwrap();
        setTitle("");
        setDescription("");
        setImage("");
 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Please select an image.");
    }
  };
```

```
/* CONFIGURATION */
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
app.use('/blog', BlogRoutes);


/* ROUTES */
app.use("/client", clientRoutes);
app.use("/general", generalRoutes);
app.use("/management", managementRoutes);
app.use("/sales", salesRoutes);


cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});



mongoose.set('strictQuery',false);
// CONFIGURATION
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));

    // User.insertMany(dataUser);
    // Product.insertMany(dataProduct);
    // ProductStat.insertMany(dataProductStat);
    // Transaction.insertMany(dataTransaction);
    // Blog.insertMany(dataBlog);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

i need to build CRUD dashboard now i can create new property to mongodb but not have field of image
i already setting cloudinary to unsigned

Answer (score 0):

The error `Upload preset must be whitelisted for unsigned uploads` error means that one of the following two options is true:

1. The preset you are sending to Cloudinary from `process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET` is marked for `Signed` uploads rather than `Unsigned`. When using [unsigned uploads](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload) i.e. without using an authentication `signature`, the Upload Preset you use must be set as `Unsigned`.
2. No value for `upload_preset` is actually being sent to Cloudinary. In other words, the parameter you're adding in the FormData has no value in which case Cloudinary would expect a `signature` to exist and if that is not passed, which won't be in your case, then the same error would be returned.

To resolve 1) you should log into your Cloudinary account, go to the Settings -> Upload tab -> Bottom of the page -> Upload Presets. There you'll be able to see the `Mode` for the Upload Preset you're trying to use - which should be marked as `Unsigned`.

To resolve 2) you could log the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET` at the start of the `uploadImageToCloudinary`  function and ensure it contains the value you expect. You could also try to hardcode the value of your preset in the FormData (value to `upload_preset` parameter) instead of getting it via `process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET` and see if that works. If so, it then means no value is coming through (or it's `undefined`) from your environment variable.